# Rails i18n and yml structure for form labels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml

According to the [ActionView documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M002292). Quote:

> The text of label will default to the attribute name unless a translation is found in the current I18n locale (through views.labels.<modelname>.<attribute>) or you specify it explicitly.

I have a "user" model and a registration form. Here's a snippet of the relevant part:

```
<% form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    ...
    <p>
    <%= f.label :username %>
    <%= f.text_field :username, :class => 'full_width' %>
    </p>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Dots hide unimportant code.

As I understand the documentation, if I provide a translation in my locale file, in this case :dk, my dk.yml looking like so:

```
dk:
    views:
        labels:
            user:
                username:
                    "blahblah"
```

Rails should translate the label text and insert "blahblah" instead of "Username".

This is not happening, so I must have missed something. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think I found another solution here.

My app was version 2.3.5. I've now changed it to 2.3.8 and `<%= f.label :username %>` now uses the translation in:

```
dk:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        username:
```

I found the hint in this ticket:

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/745-form-label-should-use-i18n

Comment: What if you want to have a label like 'Enter your first name'? I don't feel setting attribute to a phrase like that is clean, will probably lead to some problems in some specific cases. See Voldy's answer for a correct way to customize a form label. You can even use both approaches together, but Voldy's aproach will override this one on your form, and it should

Answer (score 45):

In Rails 3.1 that is a little bit changed.

```
<% form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

en:
  helpers:
    label:
      post:
        title: 'Customized title'
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Is there a release note or something that I can look at to learn more about this format?

Comment: The description for this format is available in the [ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper.label](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-label) documentation.

Comment: If the `helpers:` path is not available, i18n will fallback to the `activerecord:` path. Very clear when using the excellent i18n-debug gem.

Comment: @PieterJongsma, thank you for this precious suggestions. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `label` method you are calling is not the one from `ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper` but is in fact the `label_tag` method from `ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper`. The `form_for` method is rewriting the code in the given block by adding `_tag` to the used form helpers. So you're not looking at the documentation for the right method!

I've not yet used that method, as sometimes the label for a field can be different from multiple forms using the same model, so I've written my own helper.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. The form_for and label methods are both on `ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper` doc page, so I just assumed they worked together like that. I've changed my code to: `<%= label :user, :username %>` With the same yml file, but I still do not get the translation. Does it matter that the `label` call is within the `form_for` block?

Comment: To be honest, I've never got that feature to work. Being curious, I've just looked at Rails code and I think this is an old feature and that the documentation hasn't been fixed: `content = (text.blank? ? nil : text.to_s) || method_name.humanize` at line 473 of form_helper.rb

Comment: In that case you should use the `t` method specifying the `scope` present in your `.yml` translation file. `<%= t :title, scope: [:helpers, :label, :post] %>`.